# building node with INET getContainingNicModule(): nic module not found

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am building a wireless node and it currently looks like this

```java
 module Node extends NodeBase
 {
    parameters:
        mobility.typename = default("StationaryMobility");
        Physical.antenna.mobilityModule = default("^.^.mobility");
        @display("bgl=8;bgb=230.31801,357.28");
        *.interfaceTableModule = default(absPath(".interfaceTable"));
    gates:
        input radioIn @directIn;
    submodules:
        //Don't know what this does but need interfaceTableModule to be defined
        interfaceTable: InterfaceTable {
            parameters:
                @display("p=125,240;is=s");
        }
        Physical: Ieee802154UwbIrRadio{
            @display("p=41,74");
        }
        Link: <default("Ieee802154Mac")> like IMacProtocol {
            @display("p=41,169");
        }
        Net: BroadcastRouting {
            @display("p=41,248");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        radioIn --> Physical.radioIn;
        Physical.upperLayerOut --> Link.lowerLayerIn;
        Physical.upperLayerIn <-- Link.lowerLayerOut;
        Link.upperLayerOut --> Net.fromMac;
        Link.upperLayerIn <-- Net.toMac;
}
```

The runtime error is produced when the simulator tries to load the LinkLayer.

Runtime Error: `getContainingNicModule(): nic module not found (it should have a property named nic) for module 'network.componenet1.Link'  ... during network initialisation`

What I believe the function `getContainingNicModule` is trying to do is look for a network interface card module that is a parent of the link layer.
I have searched for the `nic` property and cannot find anything. It may be related to the `interface` property but the `inet.LinkLayerNodeBase` that I am mirroring off has no such property.

Why does it give this error?

Comment: What version of INET do you use?

Comment: INET 4.1 on OMNET 5.4

Comment: Try to change the name of submodule from `Link` to `mac` or `wlan`.

Comment: I have tried that and the error just changes to `nic module not found (it should have a property named nic) for module 'network.componenet1.wlan'`

Comment: I have now solved this problem and will answer tomorrow as a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Any module that is `like IMacProtocol` must be a submodule of a `IWirelessInterface`

By changing the `IRadio` and `IMacProtocol` implementations to the combined `IWirelessInterface` implementation in `Ieee802154UwbIrInterface` it no longer gave me the `nic module not found error.`

The function that threw the error is [findContainingNicModule](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/b89cf742b39f0a46702089ba77aa953084e05a80/src/inet/common/ModuleAccess.h#L118). It looks for if it can to a cast of a parent module to the `InterfaceEntry` type. If it fails then it thows the error to do with the `nic` property however no module has that property any longer.

Since inet 3.6.4 (I think) [Nic types have been replaced with Interface types](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/commit/0ff400d703f952fc8acb4d35f4eacf6b0580d0de). A lot of the other references to `Nic`s were not changed though. So the error doesn't accurately reflect the problem.

The working module now:

```java
module Node extends NodeBase
{

    parameters:
        mobility.typename = default("StationaryMobility");
        wlan.radio.antenna.mobilityModule = default("^.^.^.mobility");
        @display("bgl=8;bgb=230.31801,357.28");
    gates:
        input radioIn @directIn;
    submodules:
        //Don't know what this does but need interfaceTableModule to be defined
        interfaceTable: InterfaceTable {
            parameters:
                @display("p=125,240;is=s");
        }
        wlan: <default("Ieee802154UwbIrInterface")> like IWirelessInterface{
            parameters:
                @display("p=41,248,row,150;q=queue");
        }
        Net: BroadcastRouting {
            @display("p=41,148");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        radioIn --> wlan.radioIn;
        wlan.upperLayerOut --> Net.fromMac;
        wlan.upperLayerIn <-- Net.toMac;
}
```